# Right alignment first column and left align second column in div of Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I looked through the official [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) layout page and there are many examples of alignment. I am looking forward to a class that will make the layout like

[image]

Every content of the first column will start with right alignment and every content of the second column will start with left alignment. If we use `justify-content-center` class then every content starts with the center. I know how to do it using **CSS** but I don't want to do this for every content.

***Do you have any class that class will set every content in the right alignment?***

Comment: `text-right` and `text-left` on the columns can do that.

Comment: ``d-flex justify-content-end`` and ``d-flex justify-content-start`` will do the job. Use the class with the breakpoint class.

Comment: @OMiShah works for only a single tag but i want the whole column like the above attached photo

Comment: @-mhhabib even @m4n0's answer will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this is what you're looking for:**

[image]

**Source:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md text-right">
           <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150/000000/FFFFFF/" />
           <h1>Hello World</h1>
           <p>Bootstrap grid</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150/000000/FFFFFF/" />
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>Bootstrap grid</p>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```